# Result of File.createNewFile() is ignored

Tags: java, android

Please I need you to help me to find what I have been doing wrong. I have been having a problem while creating a file using android studio. 
There is no error, but the file "textstring.txt" is not created. 
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) and 
W/System.err: at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:944) are the warnings I become and it happens at myFile.createNewFile()

This is my code lines

```
private String INPUT_FILE = "textstring.txt";
private String inputString = "thisIsTheTextToWrite";

private File myFile = null;

private Button myWrite = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Create a file
    myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/Data/" + getPackageName() + "/files/" + INPUT_FILE);

    mWrite = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_write);
    mWrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(INPUT_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
                output.write(inputString.getBytes());

                if(output != null)
                    output.close();

                //
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())
                        && !Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
                {
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                    output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    output.write(inputString.getBytes());

                    if(output != null)
                        output.close();
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

The problem seems to occur at // myFile.createNewFile();
Why that ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: can you elaborate what problem you are facing? because looking at your title it seems like it just a warning. i.e you are not using the return value of method myFile.createNewFile(); you can ignore this too..

Comment: Your are rigth, there is no error, but the file "textstring.txt" is not created. **W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)** and
**W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:944)** are the warnings I become and it happens at **myFile.createNewFile()**

Answer (score -1):

It is just a warning right ?

You should always check the result of `myFile.createNewFile()` :

```
if(!myFile.createNewFile()) {
    Log.e("mDebug", "Couldn't create the file");
}
```

That's it